# Mutable list of Obersable<Object> wait until all of them finish and combine them into a List<Object>

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm not an expert in RxJava/RxAndroid and I'm having some issues with this scenario. 
Basically I have a mutable list of observable which I won't ever know the size and I want to wait until all of them are completed as well.

```
var observableList: MutableList<Observable<Object>> = mutableListOf()
```

And I would like to do something like:

```
Observable.zip(observableList,....)
```

and combine all the `Object` results into `Object<List>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Observable.concat()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-) for this and call [`toList()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList--) on it.

```
Observable.concat(observableList)
          .subscribeOn(...)
          .toList()
          .observeOn(...)
          .subscribe(...)
```

Inbetween you can also switch threads with `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` to make sure not to block the UI thread.